# Abp vNext Forget password (reset password) email template

Tags: abp

I'm using Abp vNext v3.3 and want to use Abp Text Template to overwrite existing Forget (Reset) password template, however I don't know what's the existing .tpl it uses for resetting password, I need the reset password "link" tag name within the template.

Comment: You should check the document. https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Text-Templating

Comment: Thanks for your reply, indeed my question is not for how to use the Text Template. I read the doc before asking this question. 
Instead, I'm wondering the default template that reset password email uses and I want to update the content within it especially for some predefined tags name I can use.

Comment: https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/modules/account/src/Volo.Abp.Account.Application/Volo/Abp/Account/Emailing/Templates/PasswordResetLink.tpl

Comment: Hi @maliming, thanks! One more question, if I just want to translate the text in current default WeldPasswordResetLink.tpl, how can I do? At this moment, I overwrite AccountEmailTemplateDefinitionProvider just for using my own localizationResource.

Answer (score 2):

Override the following method in your custom class, so that you can get the link and if you want you can execute the base method to continue the routine steps.

https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/modules/account/src/Volo.Abp.Account.Application/Volo/Abp/Account/Emailing/AccountEmailer.cs#L40

Note, I didn't test the code, just wrote out of my mind

```cs
[Dependency(ReplaceServices = true)]
[ExposeServices(typeof(AccountEmailer ))]
public class MyAccountEmailer: AccountEmailer {

  public virtual async Task SendPasswordResetLinkAsync(
    IdentityUser user,
    string resetToken,
    string appName,
    string returnUrl = null,
    string returnUrlHash = null) {

    /* THIS IS THE LINK. DO WHATEVER YOU WANT! */
    var link = CreateLink(user, resetToken, appName, returnUrl, returnUrlHash);

    await base.SendPasswordResetLinkAsync();
  }

  private string CreateLink(IdentityUser user,
    string resetToken,
    string appName,
    string returnUrl = null,
    string returnUrlHash = null
  ) 
  {
    var url = await AppUrlProvider.GetResetPasswordUrlAsync(appName);

    var link = $ "{url}?userId={user.Id}&tenantId={user.TenantId}&resetToken={UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(resetToken)}";

    if (!returnUrl.IsNullOrEmpty()) {
      link += "&returnUrl=" + NormalizeReturnUrl(returnUrl);
    }

    if (!returnUrlHash.IsNullOrEmpty()) {
      link += "&returnUrlHash=" + returnUrlHash;
    }

  }
}

}
```

Comment: Hi @alper-ebicoglu, thanks, this one is useful, I used it to achieve my goal.